# How can the effect of wind gradient in a glide be calculated?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics

If an airplane glides in a mass of air where the headwind changes with altitude, it seems logical to think that the length of the glide –as measured by a ground-based observer– will be longer in the case of the headwind decreasing with altitude. The reverse should be true in the case of the headwind increasing with altitude...

How could a mathematical expression for that glide be derived...?

Comment: I assume you want to assume that the pilot is manipulating the controls in such a way that the actual airspeed is always exactly equal to the airspeed that would yield best glide angle *over the ground* in a *uniform* airmass (no gradient) that was moving at the wind speed that the aircraft is currently experiencing at that instant?  So descending with a headwind with a normal gradient, the pilot is actually *decreasing* the airspeed?  (This would be a logical way to operate the controls and *I think it is the optimal way* at least in the case where no course changes are allowed.)

Comment: Or do you want to just assume constant airspeed?

Comment: Obviously *if course changes* are allowed then the problem is much more complex-- the albatross can obtain an *infinite* glide ratio over the long run in such a scenario, using dynamic soaring techniques

Comment: @quietflyer The criterion could be that of manipulating the controls in such a way as to maximize the energy extraction from the wind gradient...

Comment: This may take some time -- but it certainly should be answerable

Answer (score 1):

You have your descent rate in feet per minute, based on IAS, your aircraft, and the existing conditions (altitude, temperature, pitch, etc).  At one altitude with that IAS (and a conversion to TAS, if you're so inclined) and the winds there, you have a particular (calculable) groundspeed. So you can calculate that in each minute, you travel "this" far forward, and you lose "this" much altitude. So you can compute your descent gradient.

Passing a new altitude with different winds, your groundspeed (and, upstream of that in the calculations, your TAS) is now different, and so your forward travel per minute is different, and you have the new gradient.

That's the "slices of the cucumber" method; if you want to do a full integration to get a smooth curve (assuming that your wind data is amenable to that sort of an approach), well, you're into more math than I can recall from school days.

The other dynamic that this approach won't capture is that as you descend into an increasing headwind, you will gain IAS as the inertia of the aircraft doesn't change as quickly as the velocity of the air can change.  This effect doesn't matter much if the change in wind speed is small or gradual, but descending from 100 knots of tailwind at cruise down to 20 knots at low altitude, it matters -- you've gained energy that needs to be accounted for (and dissipated) if you're planning to cross a given fix at a specified altitude & airspeed.  Unfortunately, the 737 FMC (and probably many others) doesn't account for this effect; it only knows that your groundspeed will change with altitude.

Comment: I think the whole point of the question is surely to account for the energy actually extracted from the wind gradient, taking into account the aircraft's inertia-- i.e. the answer should not be the same for a light weight balsa glider than for a heavy massive glider even if they happen to have the same glide ratio at any given speed of interest.

Comment: @quietflyer  Since the FMC designers don't worry about that energy gain, my initial thought was the more basic math of just the gradient itself, which is what the question mentions.  Adding to that the math to account for gained/lost energy, and/or adjusting airspeed to accomplish particular goals (i.e. your comments on the OP), would have to be added on top of that basic computation.